# apple tv and roku - strong wireless?

Tags: appletv

I have a broadband dsl at home, but my wireless signal isnt that strong in the living room. I am excited with getting one of these 2 devices, but I don't know how it will all work without cable.

If I am working at home or downloading stuff, then the available bandwidth is even lesser. Does that mean bad streaming and buffering? Will these devices let me buffer the movie when I am not at home and then watch the stream later?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Roku HD has 802.11b/g WiFi. The Roku XD and XDS have 802.11b/g/n.

The Apple TV has 802.11a/b/g/n.

802.11n is the fastest network speed, and reaches the farthest. If the WiFi in your home is 802.11n, I strongly recommend choosing one of the players that supports that.

Answer (score 1):

The new (black) AppleTV has an 8GB flash onboard so it should be able to store 2 or 3 HD movies locally without having to stream them again. I have 10Mbps cable and it only takes 10 seconds or so between purchase and the show starting to play.